# Can I have 2 45 degree angles in my wall from drain to vent?

Tags: plumbing

Can I have 2  45 degree angles with a 8 inch piece of 2inch  to my bathroom sink? The drain pipe is over to far to be in side my vanity. The the clean out and vent pipe will go strait up threw my roof from there.

Answer (score 3):

If those are the only bends, and they are horizontal, and the total trap arm length is less than 5 feet, then yes. Trap arms can go thru no more than 90 degrees of bends without a clean out. Not including the vertical bends at the trap and at the drain/vent connection.